# How to filter e-mails from a specific domain and number of receivers?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to use DASL filter to:

1. Exclude a recipient's specific domain (e.g., @test.com)
2. Limit the result to one-to-one e-mail (only one recipient).

For the first point I thought about this query:

`"urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"  LIKE '%@%'AND NOT "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"  LIKE '%@test.com'`

But it's not working,I still have e-mails with @test.com in the receiver list of several e-mails.

For the second point I have no idea how to limit to one recipient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expectation is one question per post. If you cannot figure out how to limit the results to one recipient post another question with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following opertor `<>` which means not equal in the search string:

```
"urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"  LIKE '%@%' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"  <> '%@test.com'
```

Comment: I still obtain e-mail which necessarily contains one or more receiver domains different from "test.com", but also contains "test.com" sometimes. I think it's only restricted the result as "one or more e-mail receiver must have a different domain than test.com" and not "all receivers must have a different domain than test.com".

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a single condition `"urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"  <> '%@test.com'`.

Comment: I still have e-mails with receivers as "@test.com" but they appear in the receiver list with their Firstname and Lastname. Maybe the filter is not working for thise particular case

Comment: You can set up a filter in the Outlook UI and then re-use in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate filters are easier to figure out.

```vb
Private Sub FindMail_RestrictDomainTest()
    
    Dim olFolder As Folder
        
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim foundItems As Items
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set olFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    ' You could generate two separate working filters
    
    ' Filter 1
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & " Like '" & "%@%" & "'"
    Debug.Print "strFilter: " & strFilter
    
    Set foundItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print "foundItems.Count: " & foundItems.count
    
    ' Filter 2
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & "NOT urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & " Like '" & "%@test.com" & "'"
    Debug.Print "strFilter: " & strFilter
    
    ' Filter      ** foundItems **      not olFolder.Items
    Set foundItems = foundItems.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print "foundItems.Count: " & foundItems.count
    
    For i = 1 To foundItems.count
    
        If TypeOf foundItems(i) Is mailItem Then
            With foundItems(i)
                Debug.Print i & " - " & .ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print "      " & .subject
                Debug.Print "      " & .To
            End With
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    
    ' Combined filters. There is no reason to do so.
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & " Like '" & "%@%" & "' AND " & _
      "NOT urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & " Like '" & "%@test.com" & "'"
    Debug.Print "strFilter: " & strFilter
    
    Set foundItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print "foundItems.Count: " & foundItems.count
    
    For i = 1 To foundItems.count
    
        If TypeOf foundItems(i) Is mailItem Then
            With foundItems(i)
                Debug.Print i & " - " & .ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print "      " & .subject
                Debug.Print "      " & .To
            End With
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```